# Parsing a JSONP file in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, jsonp

I'm new to Angular and also relatively new to the JSONP format.   In my code, I set up a factory to read in the JSONP file - and I get back the data variable as the JSONP data properly

```
$http.get('someJSONFile').success(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

The console log gives me back the following:

```
states([{"code":"AL","name":"Alabama"},{"code":"AK","name":"Alaska"},{"code":"AZ","name":"Arizona"},{"code":"AR","name":"Arkansas"},{"code":"CA","name":"California"},{"code":"CO","name":"Colorado"},{"code":"CT","name":"Connecticut"},{"code":"DE","name":"Delaware"}])
```

So - I'm stuck on what to do now.   I have a data object that contains a function.   I need to parse out the JSON from this function - but not sure how to do it.

I have read in other places that I need to declare a function somewhere in my controller or factory called

```
function states(results)
{
    // what is in results should be the JSON data I crave
}
```

But even if I do that, I don't think it ever executes - so I am not sure what I should do at that point to get the JSON data into an object that I can use.

The full file I am trying to parse is http://massachusettswebdesigns.com/states.json

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, I think you can just call `try {eval(data) } catch (e) {}` and then in your `states` function, throw in `console.log(results)` to see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Angular `$http` service provides a [method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp) to consume JSONP endpoints. In your case this should work:

```
$http.jsonp('someJSONFile').then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

Behind the scene, Angular will create a globally accessible function that will receive data, parse and pass further, so you don't need to worry about creating functions yourself.

Comment: OK, now I am getting an error that states is not defined

Comment: Is it you own service? It is not really JSONP, you should not hard code `states` function in response. Instead you should take whatever GET parameter for callback comes from client and wrap JSON data with it.

Comment: No - not my service, and thats the problem.

Comment: Is there maybe a way to say that you want to use different function? Is this service is configurable? I checked it doesn't understand GET parameter `callback`, maybe different one? Otherwise you will have to create global function states.

Answer (score 0):

What looks like your trying to do is standard JSON not JSONP, JSONP will require a callback and is only required if getting data from a different domain, ie a API service

Also the console log output you give is not valid JSON.

```
//init app
var app = angular.module('MyApp',[]);

//setup a factory for the data handling

app.factory("Data",function($http){
return {

   getData:function(type){

   return $http.get(type).
       then(function(result) {
           return result.data;
       });
   }
}
});

//in a controller 'call' the factory for the data

app.controller('main', function main($scope, Data) {

//other stuff

Data.getData('someJSONFile').then(function (data) {
    $scope.jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
});

//other stuff
});
```

Comment: OK, this got me to a part where I got a No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource, error. 

I was able to get around that by using a plugin for Chrome that allows me to overwrite the cross origin error.   

But now when I parse the file I get an SyntaxError: Unexpected token s error when it trys to parse the state.

The file I am trying to parse is http://massachusettswebdesigns.com/states.json

Comment: Depending on the data format you may not need to parse it, ie if not a string, so change the line $scope.jsonData = JSON.parse(data); to $scope.jsonData = data;

Answer (score 0):

So my error was a stupid one.    The JSON file was giving me the name of a custom callback I had to define.   Once I did this, all worked. . . . here's the code

```
angular.module('locationApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {


    $scope.states = [];
    $scope.cities = [];


    // Function for the States callback on the JSON files provided
    window.states = function (data)
    {
      $scope.states = data;
    };

     // Get the State JSON file.   
    $http.jsonp('http://locationinc-mapping-demo.herokuapp.com/states.json');


}]) // end of MainCtrl
```